How to add a column of sequential run numbers based on time gaps in another pandas dataframe column without iterating over rows
I often  have large datasets of time ordered data that represent manufacturing operations.  But the machines stop.  Then restart.  I might define a "run" as the period where there is no gap in the data.  And for large datasets there might be many runs.
But I cannot find an elegant way in Pandas to add the run column based on time gaps.
Here is simplified example of my code:
    #Function to replace if possible
    def add_run_col(df, time_col, gap_size_in_minutes):
        run_num = 1
        run_col = [run_num]
        for row in range(1, len(df)):
           gap = df[time_col].iloc[row] - df[time_col].iloc[row - 1]
           if gap > timedelta(minutes = gap_size_in_minutes):
               run_num +=1  #Found a gap so increment run number
           #Add the run number to the list even if the if statement was false
           run_col.append(run_num)  
        df['run'] = run_col 
        return df

    #Create example data
    np.random.seed(3661)
    datetimes = pd.date_range(start='2024-09-03', end='2024-09-06', freq='1min')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': datetimes, 'meas': np.random.randint(0, 100, 
    size=len(datetimes))}).reset_index(drop=True)
    
    #Create simulated run stops -- gaps in time
    droplist = np.unique(np.sort(np.random.randint(0, len(df), size=100))).tolist()        
    df = df.drop(droplist).reset_index(drop=True)  #And make the gaps

    #Uses function above instead of something more panda like????
    newdf = add_run_col(df, 'datetime', 1)

Because of this excellent post:
How can I iterate over rows in a Pandas DataFrame?
I am thinking there is probably a better way -- one that does not require iterating over the rows.  Is there?
After searching through the various pandas time series and other functions I cannot find it.
I can create a boolean column this way, but I still cannot use it to create a numerical index that repeats between True values:
   df['rungap'] = df['datetime'].sort_values().diff() > pd.to_timedelta('1 min')

In my actual code I do sort before proceeding as I cannot assume the SQL query I use returns an ordered set.

Try:
df['run'] = df['datetime'].diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)).cumsum()

Output:
                datetime  meas  run
0    2024-09-03 00:00:00    98    1
1    2024-09-03 00:01:00    88    1
2    2024-09-03 00:02:00    64    1
3    2024-09-03 00:03:00    45    1
4    2024-09-03 00:04:00     3    1
                 ...   ...  ...
4217 2024-09-05 23:56:00    48   98
4218 2024-09-05 23:57:00    16   98
4219 2024-09-05 23:58:00    62   98
4220 2024-09-05 23:59:00    24   98
4221 2024-09-06 00:00:00    98   98

Explanation

Calculate the difference between consecutive rows with Series.diff.
Check unequal to 1 minute with Series.ne + pd.Timedelta.
Get the cumulative sum for the resulting boolean series (where True means a gap) with Series.cumsum.

Equality check with OP's method:
newdf.equals(df.astype({'run': newdf['run'].dtype}))
# True

# (`df['run']` will be `int32`, `newdf['run'] has `int64`)


Excellent, thank you.  The loop takes my system about 10400 microseconds and your solution takes 44 microseconds; a big testimonial to the "don't iterate over rows in a dataframe" recommendation.   I was not familiar with Series.ne and the other two -- Series.dff and Series.cumsum I haven't used enough to see them as part of the solution to a number of problems.  You gave me some study and practice material.

You're welcome! Here's a good general post on avoiding loops when using pandas. Otherwise, if the answer offered a solution to your Q, please consider accepting the answer to close the post.
